# How can I make an input field in ExpressionEngine required?

Tags: forms, validation, expressionengine

I've found many articles/tutorials/how-tos stating that you should add `name="required"` or `name="required[]"`, but what do you do when all of the input fields in a custom form have explicit names that are part of the forms functionality? (I tried changing the name to required, hoping the pre-existing names were cosmetic, and the form ceased working.)

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a front end entry form using Safecracker, there is a fair bit of documentation on form validation - it can be validation against field requirements (along with other validation against CodeIgniter classes) or you can use jquery for client-side validation, which often involves little more than loading the validation plugin and adding a class of required to each required form element (not typically changing the name).